# Is it a good practice to run unit tests inside build job in Gitlab CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

- We want to run unit tests against a built Docker image and not by installing the environment inside Gitlab CI runner
- We don't want to push the docker image to a registry and pull it back in a test job to run unit tests - it's slower.

But it contradicts the separation of concerns principle - now our build job will also run unit tests.

The question for the community: is it okay to sacrifice this principle in this case or there are better alternatives?

Comment: It's perfectly fine for unit tests, assuming they run in a short amount of time. Where you would need to have a distinct environment would be called integration tests - those are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: See **bold** sentence below.

---

I know the *separation of concerns (SoC) principle* mostly from a "software code organisation" point of view. I never explicitly encountered it for build job definitions up to now (which does not mean it is bad to follow it in this context too).

From my point of view: *Principles* and *good* (or even *best*) *practices* exist for a reason. Following them can help you guide your project to success, because they seem to appear often in successful projects<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

This does not mean that every successful project follows all best practices. On the other hand, following them does not automatically make your project successful.<sup>[citation needed, too]</sup>

Please note that I don't know building Docker images with GitLab well enough to give you advice in this direction. Maybe GitLab provides some special mechanism directly for this use case?

---

In your case:

The main goals of SoC are to manage complexity, increase modularity and facilitate maintenance.

I summarise the points you give in your question as *increase pipeline efficiency*.

So the questions are:

- Does "test during build" increase the performance so much that it pays the additional maintenance costs?
- How complex are the building and testing logics for themselves? How easy is it to split them apart again if you put them together now?
- To put in the two additional principles "*Premature Optimization*" and "*You Aren’t Gonna Need It*": Do you *really* need this efficiency now? On the other hand, do you *really* need the separation now?
- Maybe it is possible to do both, separate building and testing each in their own script files but call them both from one job?

**If you cannot find strong arguments in favour of one or the other now, do as you like and be prepared to refactor later when your needs become clearer.** Whatever you do, document your decision and the reasons for it together with the alternative as comments in your pipeline definition. Example:

> Build and test are done in a single job to avoid pushing/pulling the Docker image to/from registry to increase performance. If the complexity of build/test logic increases too much, split them in separate steps and check if performance is still acceptable.

This way you and your colleagues in the future can better understand *why* it is the way it is currently and whether it makes sense to change it.